# (Debian) Dragonboard 410c: Tensorflow is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, qualcomm, dragonboard

I've tried several methods for installing Tensorflow (CPU-only) onto my Dragonboard 410c, and even though all other packages install just fine, Tensorflow installation always gives me the error *tensorflow-1.3.0-...* no matter whether I use pip or pip3.

Things I've checked for:

1. `uname a` outputs arm64 (64-bit)
2. `pip -V && pip3 -V` (both 10.0.1)
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. Installing within a virtualenv
5. Installing using native pip
6. Installing using the links to the Tensorflow binaries

Even after ensuring all three of these were good, I can't install Tensorflow.

Comment: Have you considered that the problem is simply that the tensorflow wheels are not build for ARM platforms? That is the problem.